# jQuery click function exclude children except for one

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, children

I have this piece of HTML:

```
<div class="pop-up rooster-toevoegen">
    <div class="pop-up-container">
        <div class="pop-up-header clearfix">
            <div class="pop-up-title">
                Rooster toevoegen
            </div>
            <div class="sprite close"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pop-up-content clearfix">
            <form id="rooster-toevoegen-form" class="form rooster-toevoegen-form">
                <div class="afdeling-container">
                </div>
                <div class="date-container">
                </div>
                <div class="button-container clearfix">
                    <button value="" name="rooster-toevoegen-button" class="rooster-toevoegen-button button-green">Toevoegen</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want a click function on .rooster-toevoegen and exclude all children from this click function EXCEPT the button. Also the button has already a function(submitting the form), this must stay the buttons event handler.

CONTEXT:
This is a pop-up with a form inside. When the user clicks next to the pop-up the pop-up has to close. Not when clicking on the pop-up which happens when I don't exclude the children from the click event. BUT when the user clicks on the button the form has to submit. So the button should not be excluded from the click and perform his own action.

How do I do this?

Comment: So why not attach the event handler to the button ?

Comment: Sorry I will edit the post, this can be a little confusing:P

Comment: But still, why not binding event directly on button then?

Comment: you can bind multiple handlers to an element so there is nothing stopping you from adding another handler to the button

Comment: I will add some context:P

Comment: just like `$('.rooster-toevoegen-button').click(function(){...})`

Comment: You're not really understanding, and you're asking the wrong question. What you really want to know is how to prevent the default action of submitting the form, and doing something else when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent from bubbling to all elements using e.preventDefault(), and manually trigger click on button.
Better way is to bind one more click event only to button.